# How to find out the min and max value on different where condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, max, min

I want to find out min and max value on different where condition. I want to find out max value only when min value is null.

Remember lc_cont_yymm is variable and isMaxRequired, pc_cont_no, ld_Today are  parameters in the function.
Table Employees - 2125244 rows.
primary Index on - Cont_no, cont_yymm

```sql
SELECT MIN(cont_yymm) INTO lc_cont_yymm
       FROM Employees
       WHERE cont_no = pc_cont_no
       AND   ld_Today BETWEEN eff_date AND term_date;
    IF lc_cont_yymm IS NULL THEN
       IF isMaxRequired THEN
              SELECT MAX(cont_yymm) INTO lc_cont_yymm
                 FROM Employees
                    WHERE cont_no = pc_cont_no
                    AND ld_Today > term_date;
           IF lc_cont_yymm IS NULL THEN
                  RETURN '-2';
           END IF;
       ELSE
              RETURN '-2';
       END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN lc_cont_yymm;
```

This query taking much time when call repeatedly in for..loops. Even more time, when min value is null and try to find the max value. I want to optimize in better way. 
Please help on this?

Comment: Please include table DDL, sample data and expected results. You refer to a loop but you haven't shown that; this seems to be a fragment of a function so your performance issue might be, at least in part, in how you are calling this, as well as in querying the table twice in the code you've shown - you might be better off without using a function at all, but it's hard to tell from what you've shown.

Comment: @PalamCoder . . . Don't call this functionality in a loop.  There is probably a way to write *all* the processing into a single query, but it is not possible to suggest what that might be without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to combine two queries into one as

```
SELECT CASE WHEN min(cont_yymm) IS NOT NULL 
             AND max(sign(ld_Today - eff_date) * sign(ld_Today - term_date)) < 1 THEN 
                 min(cont_yymm)
       ELSE
         CASE WHEN max(sign(ld_Today - term_date)) THEN
                   max(cont_yymm)
       END 
  INTO lc_cont_yymm
  FROM Employees
 WHERE cont_no = pc_cont_no
```

One query one parse one cost.

*P.S. To be able to use aggregation for all terms I used `sign()` function instead of `>` operator or `between` keyword.*

So ,convert your code block to

```
DECLARE
  isMaxRequired boolean := false; 
  lc_cont_yymm  pls_integer;
--the other variables
BEGIN
  -- some operations
 IF isMaxRequired THEN
  SELECT CASE WHEN min(cont_yymm) IS NOT NULL 
               AND max(sign(ld_Today - eff_date) * sign(ld_Today - term_date)) < 1 THEN 
                   min(cont_yymm)
         ELSE
           CASE WHEN max(sign(ld_Today - term_date)) THEN
                     max(cont_yymm)
         END 
    INTO lc_cont_yymm
    FROM Employees
   WHERE cont_no = pc_cont_no      
 ELSE
        RETURN '-2';
 END IF;
END;
```

Comment: this is useful...but how to use "isMaxRequired" boolean condition...I have added > 0 condition on second else part

Comment: isMaxRequired check only required for max value calculation..as per your suggestion, it is for both min and max value.

Comment: @PalamCoder thanks. You can embed the query into the code block above.

Comment: I tried to use isMaxRequired in else part with max condition..but oracle not allowing..giving invalid realtional operator error.

Comment: @PalamCoder  for `select max(expression) from dual` "expression" can be a numeric field or formula or string but not a boolean ( expression ).

Comment: Hi..it somehow not working if we pass 07-May-18 as ld_today and eff_Date is 01-May-2018 and term_Date is 01-Apr-2019..there are multiple records available in similar date with every year..total are 7 records..however it's giving max value instead of min value..Please help on this.

Comment: @PalamCoder how do you pass the parameters. Try to use them comforming with ISO standard such as `date'2018-05-01'`. Moreover can you reproduce on a fiddler site such as [dbfiddle_uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2) ?

Comment: I test it with sysdate-420 as lc_today.. However if I put date condition on where clause.. It works.. Where ((lc_day between eff_date and term_date) or lc_today > term_date)